# Error: introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

A quick question for masters.

I got 2 EF model classes:

```
public class School
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("School")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Öğretmen")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }

    public School School { get; set; }
    public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Basically I want to create an one to many relationship in code-first.

But when I try to do that, I get this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Teachers_dbo.Schools_SchoolId' on table 'Teachers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Where have I made a mistake?

**EDIT**

```
  public class Note
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required,DisplayName("Başlık"), StringLength(50)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required,DisplayName("Açıklama"), StringLength(4000)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string File { get; set; }
        public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
        public int SchoolId { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }


        //Keys

        public School School { get; set; }
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
        public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

I didnt get any error for this Model and Keys..

Comment: When do you receive the exception? On adding a migration? On insert data? Could you provide some more code, please? Have a look at: [Configure ont-to-many relationships in code first](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: @ChW I'm just running the Data Initializer that I created to create the database.

Comment: @ChW btw when i made `public int? SchoolId { get; set; }` schoolId nullable, the error is getting out of the way.

Comment: Well, nullable foreign key will fix it for you. Then check your ON DELETE actions like the exception told you. I can't reproduce your exception. For me everything works like expected with your code above. Are other models involved or do you have only these two?

Comment: @Chw,  I got one more model. Now Editing question for you.

Comment: Remove the relationship from Note to School and vice versa. You could get the school by the teacher that has a relationship to the note.

Comment: ohhh... Thanks a lot @Chw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the relationship from Note to School and vice versa. You could get the school by the teacher that has a relationship to the note.

It will produce your issue.